# read csv file triggered by s3 event

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

i want to read a csv file that is triggered by s3 event, in other words, when a csv file is uploaded to s3, my lambda function will read this file and send email with info and content. My code works fine when there is no reading of the csv file, but whenever i put the reading part i can't recieve mail.
I am using **serverless framework v--1.22.0 ** and **python 2.7.**

Here is my code:

```
def csvfile(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    email_from = '****@****.com'
    email_to = '****@*****.com'
    email_subject = 'new file is uploaded'
    for record in event['Records']:
        filename = record['s3']['object']['key']
        filesize = record['s3']['object']['size']
        source = record['requestParameters']['sourceIPAddress']
        eventTime = record['eventTime']    
    with open(str(filename), 'rb') as csvfile:  
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            print row 

    email_body = "File Name :" + filename + "\n" + "File Size :" + 
    str(filesize) + "\n" +  "Upload Time :" + eventTime + "\n" + "User 
    Details :" + source + "\n" + "content of the csv file :" + row 
    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    ses.send_email(Source = email_from,
                Destination = {'ToAddresses': [email_to,],}, 
                    Message = {'Subject': {'Data': email_subject}, 'Body':
                              {'Text' : {'Data': email_body}}}
                          )
    print('Function execution Completed !!!')
```

and here is my serverless.yml file:

```
service: aws-python # NOTE: update this with your service name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
              - s3:*
              - "ses:SendEmail"
              - "ses:SendRawEmail"
              - "s3:PutBucketNotification"
          Resource: "*"

functions:
  csvfile:
    handler: handler.csvfile
    description: send mail whenever a csv file is uploaded on S3 
    events:
      - http:
          path: ''
          method: get
      - s3:
          bucket: mine2
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: .csv
```

Comment: When a csv file is created in that bucket, does the lambda trigger _at all_?

Comment: yes, the lambda trigger at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading files triggered by s3 event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928105/reading-files-triggered-by-s3-event)

Comment: yes, exactly, reading s3 two times was the main problem