# reading files triggered by s3 event

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Here is what i want to do :

1. User uploads a csv file onto AWS S3 bucket.
2. Upon file uploaded, S3 bucket invokes the lambda function that i have created.
3. My lambda function reads csv file content, then send email  with the file content and info

**Local environment**

Serverless framework version 1.22.0

Python 2.7

Here is my serverless.yml file

```
service: aws-python # NOTE: update this with your service name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
              - s3:*
              - "ses:SendEmail"
              - "ses:SendRawEmail"
              - "s3:PutBucketNotification"
          Resource: "*"

functions:
  csvfile:
    handler: handler.csvfile
    description: send mail whenever a csv file is uploaded on S3 
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: mine2
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: .csv
```

and here is my lambda function :

```
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import logging
import sys
import traceback
import csv

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from pprint import pprint
from time import strftime, gmtime
from json import dumps, loads, JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder


#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def csvfile(event, context):
    """Send email whenever a csvfile is uploaded to S3 """
    body = {}
    emailcontent = ''
    status_code = 200
    #set email information
    email_from = '****@*****.com'
    email_to = '****@****.com'
    email_subject = 'new file is uploaded'
    try:
        s3 = boto3.resource(u's3')
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        for record in event['Records']:
            filename = record['s3']['object']['key']
            filesize = record['s3']['object']['size']
            source = record['requestParameters']['sourceIPAddress']
            eventTime = record['eventTime']
        # get a handle on the bucket that holds your file
        bucket = s3.Bucket(u'mine2')
        # get a handle on the object you want (i.e. your file)
        obj = bucket.Object(key= event[u'Records'][0][u's3'][u'object'][u'key'])
        # get the object
        response = obj.get()
        # read the contents of the file and split it into a list of lines
        lines = response[u'Body'].read().split()
        # now iterate over those lines
        for row in csv.DictReader(lines):    
            print(row)
            emailcontent = emailcontent + '\n' + row 
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        status_code = 500
        body["message"] = json.dumps(e)

    email_body = "File Name: " + filename + "\n" + "File Size: " + str(filesize) + "\n" +  "Upload Time: " + eventTime + "\n" + "User Details: " + source + "\n" + "content of the csv file :" + emailcontent
    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    ses.send_email(Source = email_from,
        Destination = {'ToAddresses': [email_to,],}, 
            Message = {'Subject': {'Data': email_subject}, 'Body':{'Text' : {'Data': email_body}}}
            )
    print('Function execution Completed')
```

i don't know what i did wrong, cause the part when i just get info about the file works fine, it's when i add the reading part that the lambda function doesn't return anything

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suggest to add to your IAM policy also the access to Cloudwatch.
Actually your lambda function is not returning anything, but you can see your log output in Cloudwatch. I really recommend to use `logger.info(message)` instead of `print` when you are setting up `logger`.

I hope that this helps to debug your function.

Except the part of sending, this is how I will rewrite it (just tested in the AWS console):

```
import logging
import boto3

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    email_content = ''

    # retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    logger.info('Reading {} from {}'.format(file_key, bucket_name))
    # get the object
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
    # get lines inside the csv
    lines = obj['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
    for r in lines:
       logger.info(r.decode())
       email_content = email_content + '\n' + r.decode()
    logger.info(email_content)
```

Comment: hey bro, that really helped, thanks a lot, i did get the answer, in facrt in my code i did write two       s3 =boto3.resource(u's3')    
            s3 = boto3.client('s3')    this was the error.

Comment: Just a little improvement - its better to initialize database connections, sdks, etc out of handler function (at global level). Lambda service preserves context of a function, therefore subsequent calls are executed much faster -
more at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html

Comment: Good point, I moved the initialization of the s3 client outside the lambda handler